# Centering image within div using css

Tags: html, css

I'm using JSSOR image gallery and currently it is stretching portrait images.

I have made a css class where it is no longer stretching:

[image]

However I can't get the imace centered in the div.

```
<div>
    <div class="portrait" u=image style="background-image: url(../img/zachry/1.jpg">&nbsp;</div>
    <div u="thumb"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS?

```
.portrait {
position: relative;
width: 850px; 
height: 565px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-align: center;
}
```

How can I get the image centered?

Comment: `background-position: center;`

Comment: text-align applies to children of the div. the background is not a child.

Comment: Pangloss's answer works. Thanks.

Comment: @Pangloss Make that a real answer

Comment: Why are you not using an `<img>` tag? Using CSS to display images for a carousel/slideshow seems wrong to me.

Comment: @hungerstar because I need a div so I can center the image within it.

Comment: @DavidTunnell you're doing it wrong then. Not saying you can't use DIVs for the slides, or should I say, _inside_ the slides, but setting images as a background image via CSS feels like bad ju-ju. I would expect to see something like this: `<div class="slide"><img src="image.jpg"></div>`.

Comment: It's fine to use both background images or inline images I think, depending what you need. There is one advantage of using background is you can use `background-size:cover` etc. to get different size images to display nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an image as a background from a `div`.

Almost any element has an attribute called: `background-position` which can take `center` as value to center the image given into the middle from the element.

so it could be something like:

```
.portrait {
    ...
    background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the following code in your CSS should work:

```
background-position: center;
```

Comment: You should explain why.

Answer (score 1):

I think of two possible ways....

1. `div {background-position: center;}`
2. `div {margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}`